# How to submit the latest build in App Store Connect?

Tags: app-store-connect

I have uploaded 3 builds in the past. When I go to the app store tab and submit, it always submits the oldest version. How do I submit the latest build?

BTW I have expired the former builds in TestFlight, as shown by the screenshot below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under the App Store tap, there is a section called build. Before submitting, you can delete the selected build by clicking the red delete button on the right. Then you'll be able to select a build.